# Executar php ao clicar, com jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu estou tentando fazer uma função com jQuery (Eu vi uma vez em jQuery), onde ao clicar em um link, executa uma página php em segundo plano.
Obs.: Não sou bom com jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#botao").click(function(){
        //apenas executa uma página após o click do usuário final em um botão.
        //nada é feito além de execução da página, nenhum aviso, nada.
        //não é enviado qualquer parâmetro para para pagina.php.
        //permanece na página atual sem qualquer alteração.
        $função_que_executa_pagina: 'pagina.php';
      }); 
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--botão que executa o código-->
    <a id="botao" href="#">
  </body>
</html>
```

Tentei assim é não funcionou.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#botao').on('click', function () {
     url = 'pagina.php';
     var aClasse = this.id;
     $.ajax({
       url: url,
     }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--botão que executa o código-->
    <a id="botao" href="#">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
  </body>
  </script>
</html>
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, já agradeço.

Comment: Qual exatamente o seu problema? Edite sua pergunta e nos forneça mais informações como o HTML correspondente, onde você define essa variável **pUrl**...

Comment: Márcio, de onde vem a variável `purl`? O que pretende passar para o PHP?

Comment: O que pretende com `url : 'pagina.php'`? O que espera que iso faça? Se não souber diga que não sabe, mas assim é dificil perceber o que quer...

Comment: Pois é, eu peguei esse código na internet e tentei editar, pois não entendo de jQuery (nem javascript).

Comment: quero executar pagina.php para que ela altere o status da notificação para 'visualizado'.

Comment: Eu tenho algo exatamente como as notificações do Facebook, ao clicar pra ver, já marca como visualizado.

Comment: Também gostaria que estivesse duplicado, mas não tem nada haver com o outro post. Não quero carregar uma página na outra, apenas executar uma página php sem sair da página em que está, sem a percepção o usuário final.

Comment: É exatamente a mesma coisa @MárcioTeixeira

Comment: Utilize Ajax! Não há atualização da página desta forma, o navegador faz a requisição sem dar reload.

Comment: Fiz a releitura da pergunta e não identifiquei similaridade. Sei que não estou sendo claro, pois não conheço os comandos do jQuery. Alterei a pergunta para tentar esclarecer.

Comment: Como fazer em Ajax? Marcelo Aymone.

Comment: Não é uma duplicata exata mesmo, mas as respostas lá servem quase integralmente para o seu caso. Use uma chamada ajax igual a que está na resposta aceita da outra pergunta, e altere somente o que está dentro da função de `success` (o que é para ser feito após receber uma resposta do php; pode não ser nada).

Comment: Exatamente como colocou o @bfavaretto...

Comment: Acho que o problema dele é ter declarado a referência ao jQuery depois de ter usado a função `$`.